# cygwin gawk get weird result

Tags: bash, cygwin, gawk

I run this command in cygwin:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS="[NDMmS E]";}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}' README.txt
```

and I got this(assume this is result1):

```
1               1290             037 35 38.6     105 10
2               1273             037 34 55.9     105 08
3               1353             037 39 46.8     105 12
4               1306             037 38 23               105 21
5               1314             037 40 08               105 22
6               1270             037 34 52               105 22
... omitted....
```

and if I remove the `E` between the `FS=[ ]` part like this:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS="[NDMmS ]";}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}' README.txt
```

I got(result2):

```
1               1290             037 35 38.6    E105 10 0.05
2               1273             037 34 55.9    E105 08 13.9
3               1353             037 39 46.8    E105 12 15.17
```

---

my question is :

1),why if I added `E`, in result1, the tail part is missing?, I mean `0.05` for the first line.

2),how to get ride off the 'E' in result2, if I want to import the data to EXCEL for example.

this is the 'README.txt' file:

---

```
1       1290m       N037D35M38.6S   E105D10M0.05S
2       1273m       N037D34M55.9S   E105D08M13.9S
3       1353m       N037D39M46.8S   E105D12M15.17S
....
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I found that it’s just because I only printed the first 8 fields! If I added `E`, there are 9 fields. It’s not the re-expression’s fault, it’s my fault.